# Site not being indexed by Bing

Tags: search, seo, indexing, search-engine, bing

Dashboard screenshot:

Image located here: http://s8.postimage.org/uckgo85xf/bing_issue.gif

I'm having problems getting my site indexed by Bing. I can't see anything particularly wrong with the setup so far but maybe someone can help me out. I've submitted the sitemap to the system and it has been successfully submitted. Bing has discovered 100+ 301 redirects, which sounds right, but neither of them have been indexed by Bing. As you can see it appears at one point the pages were indexed then took a dramatic dive from 200+ to 0, dropping -100%.

See here for drop: http://i45.tinypic.com/20pab6a.gif

Any thoughts? Has anyone encountered this before too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think about two possibilities:

1) The site owns many pages with duplicate content (and punished by Bing)

2) The site owns these lines in robots.txt to not to index site for Bing:

```
User-agent: bingbot
Disallow: /
```

You can check these two points.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Point one, there could be a possibility of slight duplication, does Bing punish this type of thing by removing the whole site from index? On point two, the robots.txt file doesn't contain that. It only has this...

User-agent: *
Allow: /

Comment: Bing punishes duplicate content harder than Google. It's not rare to see a young website totally disappear from the index.